# Dynamic html mail process through single list with exact target fuel sdk

Tags: php, newsletter, exacttarget

I want to send mails through single list every week. html mail and text mail both.
It is possible to create one list like "12548" and add the different user like "abc@gmail.com","xys@yahoo.com", and more.
Sent the one html newsletter for one user. means different user for different html newsletter.
Also sent me process with fuel sdk (php).

I have one list like "Newsletter(12548)" which has 5000 users.How i send the newsletter to every user.So i want to send the newsletter to every user with different html newsletter.

Every user is having separate newsletter.I am using this [concept](https://code.exacttarget.com/getting-started)  but i want to have one list and send different/customised newsletter to every user.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

ExactTarget has a server-side scripting language called AMPScript that allows you to send emails with dynamic content to a list of subscribers. So, you don't want to actually be sending 5000 different pre-created emails to 5000 different people for what should be a single send; you can create one email in ExactTarget that uses AMPScript to personalize the email for each subscriber on a list (this is described briefly at the bottom of the link you provided).

The email script runs separately for each subscriber on the list, so individual subscriber attributes are available in the scripting context for customizing the sent email content. If you are managing everything through the API with PHP, the HTML and AMPScript will need to be defined in a string for the body of the Email object being used in the send. The Email object should have separate properties for defining the HTMLBody versus the TextBody, and there is actually a default preference attribute on the subscriber that defines whether the HTML or text version should be used.

AMPScript documentation:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/